# orthocomplement of a finite-dimensional Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space. Moreover, let $\mathcal{P}_2 \in \mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{P}_3 \in \mathcal{H}$ be a *finite-dimensional* and an *infinite-dimensional* closed sub-spaces of $\mathcal{H}$.
In a book, the *orthocomplement of $\mathcal{P}_2$ in $\mathcal{P}_2 + \mathcal{P}_3$* is indicated as:
\begin{equation*}
   \mathcal{W} \triangleq  (\mathcal{P}_2 + \mathcal{P}_3) \cap \mathcal{P}_2^\perp.
  \end{equation*}
I cannot understated which elements are in $\mathcal{W} \in \mathcal{H}$... In may study case, I can explicitly write down $\mathcal{P}_2$, $\mathcal{P}_3$ and $\mathcal{P}_2^\perp$ but I don't know how to combine them to get $\mathcal{W}$.

Comment: Isn't this the orthogonal projection of $P_3$ onto $P_2^\perp$?

Comment: If $w\in W\subset P_2^\perp$, there is $y\in P_2$ such that $w+y\in P_3$. So $w$ is the projection of $x+y$ in the direction of $y$.